# Can I save user latitude to a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, api, browser, geolocation

I can't pull the latitude or longitude out of the browsers API and have been trying for probably two weeks. Have been reading everything I can find and taking a class on functions, but this is just over my head. Is there a way I can save it to a variable so I plug it into another function. Have tried a couple ways

Way 1:

```
const x = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({coords})) => {
    return pos.coords.latitude
}
```

Way 2:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    if ((splitCoords[1] - position.coords.latitude >= -0.009 && splitCoords[1] - position.coords.latitude <= 0.009) && 
    (splitCoords[0] - position.coords.longitude >= -0.009 && splitCoords[0] - position.coords.longitude <= 0.009))
    {
        return "Yes"
    } else {
        return "No"
    }
})
```

What's throwing me off is the fact that getCurrentPosition() is, itself, a function.. and I can't find anywhere that shows me how to query certain coordinates out of it. I console.logged the whole thing in the browser and went down the tree and 'coordinates' don't exist. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Have you read ]the documentation for `getCurrentPosition`?

Comment: I read the MDN page about 15 times -- I can't make sense of it so I asked here but found the answer on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ls013DBcww

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer in a series of youtube videos starting [with this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ls013DBcww). The videos are awesome, highly recommend for anyone who stumbles across this looking for a solution.